# Awodey's Category Theory: I don't understand the matrix notation in example

Tags: matrices, category-theory, notation

In page 7 of Awodey's book there is an example using matrices as arrows. I don understand the notation $F = (n_{ij})_{i<a,j<b}$, and I can't construct one of those matrices.

Here is the example:
[image: example page 7]

Comment: It just means the matrix $F$ whose entry in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column is $n_{i j}$, where $i \in \{ 0, \ldots, a - 1\}$ and $j \in \{ 0, \ldots, b - 1 \}$.

Comment: Let $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{3,4,5\}$. The matrix should be rectangular. What is the size of $F : A \rightarrow B$ and how I construct it?

Comment: In this case $a = 2$ and $b = 3$. The actual elements of the set are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Now I understand the notation, it remains for me to understand how the category works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means
$$
F = \begin{pmatrix}
n_{00} & n_{01} & \cdots & n_{0,b-1} \\
n_{10} & n_{11} & \cdots & n_{1,b-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
n_{a-1,0} & n_{a-1,1} & \cdots & n_{a-1,b-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$